# Combining a date and time together using a Crystal report sql command

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, command, report

I am creating a SQL command in Crystal Reports.

I have a date field and a time field but need to convert this to a single datetime field.

How can this be done in a command??

I have tried the following but just get a syntax error.

```
Cast(startdate as datetime) + Cast(startime as datetime) AS Datetime
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to reference the fieldnames correctly, e.g. `"tablename"."startdate"`  instead of `startdate`.

This command field syntax does work with an SQL Server 2016 (note that I had to cut off the date part of the second column here):

```sql
    CAST (CAST("tablename"."fieldname" AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + 
    CAST (CAST("tablename"."fieldname" AS TIME) AS DATETIME)
```

*Edit 2021-05-20:*

You could also use a **Crystal formula field** instead of a Command field to combine date and time parts of datetime fields, like so:

```
Date({tablename.fieldname1}) + Time({tablename.fieldname2})
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didnt work. Crystal reports seems to not recognise DATETIME as a function

Comment: If you're using "command" fields, it's not Crystal Reports which interprets the content, but the database server you're querying. The example does work in MSSQL 2016 as stated. Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: We are using an Openedge 11.7 Progress database via an ODBC connection

Comment: Don't know Openedge, so I cannot help with the syntax. In case you must use commands, you could inspect the SQL Crystal produces and compare with it with something that works on your DBMS. An alternative way would be to use CR formula field for that - edited my answer accordingly.